# Will that be a crossdomain XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

If I make a XMLHttpRequest from somesubdomain.example.com to someothersubdomain.example.com, will that be consider as a crossdomain request? I mean, would I have to provide Access-Control- headers to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`somesub.example.com` and `someother.example.com` are **different** hosts. Therefore, they're subject to the [Same origin policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy).

Answer (score 0):

Two pages have the same origin if the protocol, port (if one is specified), and host are the same for both pages. If there is a difference , the same will be considered as a cross origin request. Reference:
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Adding to previous comment, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.